# Size of Pre-Master Secret?

Tags: tls

I am implementing **TLS 1.2** and using cipher **ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**

According to RFC 5346 [Section 8.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-64) length of premaster secret will vary depending on key exchange method.

So, what is the size of premaster secret according to above key exchange method?

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-5.10)

> All ECDH calculations (including parameter and key generation as well
> as the shared secret calculation) are performed according to [IEEE 1363, 2000]
> using the ECKAS-DH1 scheme with the identity map as key derivation    function (KDF), so that **the premaster secret is the x-coordinate of    the ECDH shared secret elliptic curve point represented as an octet    string**.  Note that this octet string (Z in IEEE 1363 terminology) as  output by FE2OSP, the Field Element to Octet String Conversion    Primitive, has constant length for any given field; leading zeros found in this octet string MUST NOT be truncated.

More specifically, it is the `byte count of the prime of the Elliptic Curve Field` that you are using to exchange your keys.